# Prevent HTML data from being posted into form textboxes

Tags: php, mysql, html, validation, xss

I'm making a web application using PHP in where I have a form that makes entries into a MySQL database and later displays it on another webpage. But the problem is that the text boxes in the form tend to accept HTML content making the application vulnerable to XSS hacks. How do I convert HTML to plain text before I display it in the webpage.

Please feel free to ask questions in case I lack providing any information.
---------------------------------------(UPDATE)----------------------------------------
Many of you fellow mates have suggested the use of `htmlspecialchars` but in that case, if I were to allow user to refer to other pages using hyperlinks, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars) is one to to prevent xss

[strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) also strips out PHP tags

also make sure to use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or the like to prevent [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

**UPDATE**
in response to your update, the simplest way to do that would be to use one of the many [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntaxes ala [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus).  Since the markdown syntax are not HTML/PHP tags, it should pass through the PHP functions without problem, but I have never implemented this myself, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That answer really helped. The strip _tags work great. They served the best and to the greatest extent. Cheers. :)

Comment: Is there any way of cascading the functionalities of strip_tags and htmlspecialchars, so that I can execute certain tags and show the code of the rest as plaintext?

Comment: you should be able to do a simple: `$clean_text = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($text));`

Answer (score 2):

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is one of your friends for that, you may also want to replace utf8, hexencoded or entitified version of < to avoid obfuscated script to get through.

Answer (score 1):

[there you go](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)