# Is it possible to execute some tags within a textarea as leaving the rest as plaintext?

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing a php-based web application in which there is a text area within which user can type whatever he/she wants and the content later gets displayed on another page after being stored in a database. The scenario is that the user can type in HTML tags. But as far as functionality constraints are concerned, I wish to allow the user to execute some tags such as `<a>`, `<div>` etc., leaving the rest of the tags to be displayed as plaintext.
I had previously pasted this question:
[[Prevent HTML data from being posted into form textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970986/prevent-html-data-from-being-posted-into-form-textboxes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970986/prevent-html-data-from-being-posted-into-form-textboxes)
But it answered only the ways such as `strip_tags()` and `htmlspecialchars()` which either stripped the html content completely displaying the remaining plaintext or displayed everything as plaintext with no option for adding any tag as exception, respectively. Please help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). This is a library specially designed for this.

It seems it can handle any form of xss attack. See also the [comparison](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison) page.

Answer (score 0):

as told in the last post , strip_tags() is the answer, if you bothered to read the manual page for [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) ,you will see you can tell it what tags to allow, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I read the manual page but the point is that it completely removes the tags that are not added as exceptions from the content. I want the rest or the tags to be displayed as plaintext.

Comment: the point is that I want to allow users to show some code on the page if they wish, just as we do in stackoverflow. Do you have a better idea to display code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) for `strip_tags` and you'll see that the second (optional) argument accepted is an array of allowable tags.

Comment: Strip tags remove the tags that are not added in the optional argument completely from the content. I want the tags not added in the optional argument to show up as plaintext, i.e., I want something that has a combination of functionalities of Strip tags and htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Misunderstood it. Never mind D: More sleep is needed methinks. Looks like you should just run a htmlspecialchars and reconvert the required tags back with a regex**

Get PHP's translation table and strip out the ones you don't want, then call strtr();

```
$table = get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS);
$table['allowed_tag'] = "";
$table['another_allowed_tag'] = "";
strtr($str, $table);
```

I haven't tested but it should work.